# Why is the MVP being transposed in DirectX example

Tags: c++, directx, matrix-multiplication

I found this in our internal code as well and I'm trying to understand what is happening.

In the following code: https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12MeshShaders/src/MeshletRender

They do `Transpose(M * V * P)` before sending it to the shader. In the shader it's treated as a row-major matrix and they do `pos * MVP`. Why is this? I have similar code where we multiply the MVP outside in a row-major matrix and then insert it into the shaders row-major matrix, and then we do `mul(pos, transpose(mvp))`.

We have similar code for PSSL where we do the `M * V * P` and send it to the shader where we have specified that the matrix is `row_major float4x4` but then we don't have to do `transpose`.

Hopefully someone can help me out here because it's very confusing. Does it have to do with home the memory is handled?

Comment: Where do they send it to the shader?

Comment: line 336 in https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12MeshShaders/src/MeshletRender/D3D12MeshletRender.cpp

Comment: This sample uses row-major matrices, so it transforms it for the HLSL part which is (by default) column-major https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-per-component-math#matrix-ordering

Comment: The confusion arises because HLSL assumes matrices are stored in memory as column-major (which is why we transpose in Direct3D before sending to HLSL), but the maths remains row-major, hence why vec-matrix multiplication i.e. `mul(pos, MVP)` yields correct results.
The -Zpr shader compilation flag makes HLSL read matrices in memory as row-major and hence transposing matrices in D3D is no longer required, but this only works reliably with 4x4 matrices. It can get complicated very quickly if using 4x3 matrices as well. Best to stick with the default D3D/HLSL conventions.

Comment: Heya! I realized last night that hlsl is column-major now, and I was just gaslighting myself. Everyone on my team has been using directx when it was row-major and a lot of docs I find tells me it was. But I guess DX11 has changed this. Thanks for confirming it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got confirmed that DX11 is column-major.

> On line 32, the combined model-view-projection matrix is computed by
> multiplying the projection, view, and world matrix together. You will
> notice that we are post-multiplying the world matrix by the view
> matrix and the model-view matrix by the projection matrix. If you have
> done some programming with DirectX in the past, you may have used
> row-major matrix order in which case you would have swapped the order
> of multiplications. Since DirectX 10, the default order for matrices
> in HLSL is column-major so we will stick to this convention in this
> demo and future DirectX demos.
>
> Using column-major matrices means that we have to post-multiply the
> vertex position by the model-view-projection matrix to correctly
> transform the vertex position from object-space to homogeneous
> clip-space.

From https://www.3dgep.com/introduction-to-directx-11/

And https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-per-component-math#matrix-ordering

> Matrix packing order for uniform parameters is set to column-major by
> default.

Hope this saves someone from going insane.

Comment: It's more accurate to say that by convention, DirectX samples are usually *row-major matrices* and the HLSL shaders are usually *column-major matrices*, so the code will do a transpose as it sets the Constant Buffer. The actual convention used by the application is up to developer choice as long as it's consistent.